# Can't turn back to PIL Image after expanding dimensions with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I need to add a dimension to a PIL image so it is accepted as input by a library I'm using, but it gives me an error. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

printscreen = Image.open('datasets/custom/spaceship.jpg').convert('RGB')
printscreen = np.uint8(np.expand_dims(np.array(printscreen), axis=0))
printscreen = Image.fromarray(printscreen)
```

It says this: 'TypeError: Cannot handle this data type' in the last line.

Comment: try doing a `print(type(printscreen))` right above `printscreen = Image.fromarray(printscreen)` to ensure it is the correct type

Comment: @Reedinationer It just prints `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: You can set the type when creating the array by doing `np.array(printscreen, dtype=np.uint8)`. Also, to check the type of a numpy array you can use the `dtype` attribute. For example: `print(printscreen.dtype)`

Comment: So if your original image was 512x512 pixels of greyscale, it would become 512,512,3 when you make it RGB. Then you expand it to 1,512,512,3 and hope PIL can make an image of that? It can't, it can only do 2-d images in up to 3 or 4 colours, not 4-d.

Comment: You **can** make an image from the first in the list with `i=Image.fromarray(printscreen[0])`

Answer (score 1):

**2 solutions:**

**Number 1: (You just want alpha channel) Just convert it as RGBA (you will get 4th channel)**

```
printscreen = Image.open('some_image.jpg').convert('RGBA')
```

**Number 2: More flexible and general attitude towards expanding dimension**

1) Inquire 2D size of image

2) create 2D 'grayscale' image filled with zeros

3) concatenate your original 3D image with 'grayscale' image

4) result is 4 channeled image, with one channel being set to 0

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

printscreen = Image.open('some_image.jpg').convert('RGB')
temp = np.asarray(printscreen)
shp = temp.shape
printscreen = np.concatenate((temp,np.zeros(shape=[shp[0],shp[1],1])),axis=2)

printscreen = Image.fromarray(printscreen.astype(np.uint8))
```

---

```
>>> printscreen.shape # before transformed with Image.fromarray
(397, 397, 4)
```

**Edit - General attitude to put matrixes upon themselves:**

In case you want more images upon themsels:

*(its the same as solution 2, but more expressive)*

```
img1 = np.zeros(shape = [10,10,3])
img2 = np.zeros(shape = [10,10,3])
img_1_2 = np.concatenate((img1,img2),axis = 2)

>>> img_1_2.shape
(10, 10, 6)
```

**Edit 2:**

Just for your information, the reason why you are getting error is because you are trying to transform numpy array into PIL Image in non-image format. The shape is the problem - you had something like (x,y,3,1). The function np.expand_dims does exactly what it says - it add new dimension, that means, you are are actually doing from image a movie/video. Grayscale image is 2 dimensional, RGB or RGBA is 3 dimensional and movie is 4 dimensional, where 4th dimension is time(or better to say sequences of images). Doing transformation between RGB to RGBA doesnt expand dimension but 'volume', or in more clear words, it expands the color dimension from length 3 to length 4

**EDIT 3: You really want to expand to 4th dimension where the extra dimension will be filled with new images**

This solution doesnt count with PIL, because PIL has nothing to do with this

```
import numpy as np


class ImageContainer(object):
    def __init__(self,first_image):
        self.container =  np.uint8(np.expand_dims(np.array(first_image), axis=0))

    def add_image(self,image):
        print(image.shape)
        temp = np.uint8(np.expand_dims(np.array(image), axis=0))
        print(temp.shape)
        self.container  = np.concatenate((self.container,temp),axis = 0)
        print(self.container.shape)

    def save_all(self,name):
        np.save(name,self.container)


img1 = np.zeros(shape = [10,10,3]) # RGB
img2 = np.zeros(shape = [10,10,3]) # RGB

cont = ImageContainer(img1)
cont.add_image(img2)

>>
(1, 10, 10, 3) # 1 image
(2, 10, 10, 3) # 2 images
```

Comment: You may be right but I'm not sure OP is trying to add an alpha layer. He is possibly trying to pass a list of images, with just one element, to his library. We'll see! 

Comment: well doesnt it solution 2 express it? For you, I added edit

Comment: Yes, I probably should have clarified that. All I want to do is wrap the array inside another one, because usually it is intended to be an array of images, but I just have one. I believed it was possible to just add a dimension and turn the array into a PIL Image, because that's the type of input it accepts.

Comment: Now I dont really know what you want to do. But I putted edit 3 which expands dimension with possibility to add new images to array. I think I have exhausted all possibilites :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adaptation of some image processing code I've used previously. I'm not sure if it is the best method, or what you are looking for, but it worked for me in converting from a PIL image to an array and back

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

print_screen = Image.open('datasets/custom/spaceship.jpg').convert('RGB')
x, y = print_screen.size
print('Converting from Image to Array')
color = np.zeros((x, y, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # initialize zeros array
for i in range(0, x): # fill the array
    for j in range(0, y):
        color[i][j] = print_screen.getpixel((i, j)) #input RGB to array
print_screen = Image.fromarray(color)
```

Hopefully this will help you out!

Comment: This one will take ages to be processed. Image processing should avoid loops

Comment: I figured, hence my "I'm not sure if it is the best method", but hey it got the job done for me!